# Regex tags allow 4 words max 3 commas

Tags: php, regex

> I need to allow a maximum of 4 tags (words) and they should be
>   seperated by a comma. So for example:

`*This, is, 4, tags`* **<== should be ok!**

`*now, 3, tags*` <== should be ok!

`*or, 2*` <== should be ok!

`*one*` <== should be ok!

But..
`*this, is, more, than, 4, tags*` **<== should not work!**

Comment: regex, needs to be regex in the html

Comment: @u_mulder: because regex syntax in php has slight differences with regex syntax in grep, per example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
^[^,]+(,[^,]+){0,3}$
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact, your code with \S also works with spaces here.

Comment: \S means for non-white characters. I have shortened the regex.

Comment: @sabuj: Mine is shorter ; )

Comment: @AlexJurado-Bitendian Yeah B-) just saw it!

Answer (score 1):

Use `/^\w+(,\s*\w+){0,3}$/`:

```
preg_match('/^\w+(,\s*\w+){0,3}$/', 'This, is, 4, tags');             # 1
preg_match('/^\w+(,\s*\w+){0,3}$/', 'now, 3, tags');                  # 1
preg_match('/^\w+(,\s*\w+){0,3}$/', 'or, 2');                         # 1
preg_match('/^\w+(,\s*\w+){0,3}$/', 'one');                           # 1
preg_match('/^\w+(,\s*\w+){0,3}$/', 'this, is, more, than, 4, tags'); # 0
```

See a demo: http://ideone.com/H70gJD

Answer (score 1):

Not really a job for regex...

```
$tags = explode(",",$input_string);
if( count($tags) > 4) die("Too many tags!");
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a solution:

```
^([^,]*,?[^,]*){3}$
```